# Do you know any mathematical group / union / society at facebook?

Tags: group-theory

Do you know any mathematical group / union / society at facebook to find other mathematicians and discuss new mathematical problems? 
Yes, I know that Math.StackExchange is a similar society by itself, but I'm specifically interested in Facebook group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One that is pretty cool and educational is:

[mathematical theorems you had no idea existed, cause they're false](https://www.facebook.com/BestTheorems/)